# Changing configuration of net core application running on kubernetes

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, appsettings, .net-5

I have a ASP.NET Core Worker Service which gets some information like thread count, batch size etc. from `appsettings.json`. These settings will only take affect on startup and cannot be change when the service is running.
The application will be running in a kubernetes cluster.

What is the best practice for changing these settings while deployed in production?
What I need to have done is, changing the settings and restart the service.

I can come up with these solution:

1. Mapping `appsetttings.json` to a volume, to be able to change it, so that when container is restarted the appsettings is not reverted.

   - Do I need to move the `appsettings.json` file to another folder then root? Is there something about not mapping the running application to a volume?
2. Update the containers environment variables to override settings.

   - Will these settings be reverted back when the container is restarted?)

Any other ideas?

Comment: The environment variables are provided bu *Kubernetes*, not the container. This allows Kubernetes to spin up as many container instances as needed and provide the same configuration to all of them, through environment variables

Comment: In general my impression is, that much of the mental work when moving from explictly hosted environment like webserver or hand rolled container even is that move from appsettings/ configuration files towards environment variables which can typically be controlled by the platform, be that Azure ACI/ AKS or straight Kubernetes on something, not sure i'm totally through that journey myself when thinking architectures, especially when cloudifying existing systems.

Comment: This is an old post that I wrote, but what I ended up doing is create a quick and effective CI/CD, have 3 different appsettings.json for production, testing and development, and whenever I need to change the settings and would just redeploy. Other then doing redeploy, I would use configmaps, volumes, Azure Key Vault or Azure Configuration Manager

Answer (score 2):

If your application can be configured both with a configuration file and with environment variables, my experience has been that using environment variables is easier.  There are several aspects of this:

- You can directly include the environment variable in your deployment specification

  ```yaml
  env:
     - name: SOME_CONFIG_SETTING
       value: its value
  ```

  For a config file you need to [create a separate ConfigMap object, add it to a per-pod volume, and mount the volume in a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume).  That's routine and well-documented, but harder than just setting an environment variable.
- If you use [Helm](https://helm.sh) to deploy your application, it's very easy to substitute a configuration value at deploy time

  ```yaml
  - name: SOME_CONFIG_SETTING
     value: {{ .Values.someConfigSetting | default "its value" }}
  ```
- If you change the value of the environment variable in the deployment spec, that's enough of a change to automatically delete and recreate the pods running the container; that is, you will get an automatic restart.  If the configuration settings are in a ConfigMap, absent some [Helm hackery](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments), you will need to manually restart the deployment when the configuration changes.

You should not use `kubectl exec` here, and you should not need to try to manually restart the process running inside a container.  If a pod is managed by a deployment, `kubectl delete pod deployment-name-12345-abcde` will cause it to immediately be recreated, effectively restarting that replica of the service.

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes, the suggested way of having these type of configuration settings of non-confidential data is to use the configmap api

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

This gives You 1 MB, which should be fine for a typical appsettings file

we're adviced to use yaml format instead of json here and an example from link could be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app-settings
data:      
  MyKey: "my-value"
  MySecondKey: "my other value"

  # file-like keys, completely optional naming 
  # the app.properties and the operation.properties are just examples
  app.properties: |
    obj.property=value1, value2
    obj2.property-with-dash=value 3    
  operation.properties: |
    obj3.property=value3, value1
    obj4=value4, value 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content of your application json you may store it inside [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) or [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) and then mount it into the pod.

Both ConfigMap and Secret are stored in Kubernetes API and are always mounted into the pod read-only. Please read provided links to understand how to create and mount them inside your pods.

Answer (score 1):

Because Kubernetes creates a symlink reference to the settings file . So the file's modification date is not updated so changes are not detected by the .NET core file provider . Only the reference of the symlink changed.

Here is an alternative : https://github.com/fbeltrao/ConfigMapFileProvider

Comment: Consider giving an example, so that you extract what is the takehome from your provided link, so that the reader will not have to follow the link and understand what is the important teaching, provided you did that already, it will improve the answers usability much.

Comment: Yes maybe. But i still think my answer is more helpful than yours for instance ^^

Comment: Maybe what Ismael? my advice was to include what to take out from the link You've provide, so in order to use Your presumable vast intellect and understanding, instead of putting on the asker to figure it out, which was what problem caused the action.
As for whose answer is more helpful than other, i'm sorry i don't deal with competition. I tried to help in the way I suggested also You should do. I am not trying to better You. Yours using a FileProvider is an alternative choise and not one i would make, but if you could, and would, seeing both would shurely help even more imo.